# pandas, melt, unmelt preserve index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, linear-programming

I've got a table of clients (coper) and asset allocation (asset)

```
A = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
idx = ['coper1','coper2','coper3']
cols = ['asset1','asset2']

df = pd.DataFrame(A,index = idx, columns = cols)
```

so my data look like

```
        asset1  asset2
coper1       1       2
coper2       3       4
coper3       5       6
```

and I want to run them through a linear optimization (i've got constraints- somtehing like `sum of all of asset_i <= amount_on_hand_i` and `sum of coper_j = price_j`)

so I have to turn this 2D matrix into a 1D vector.  Which is easy with melt

```
df2 = pd.melt(df,value_vars=['asset1','asset2'])
```

But now, when I try to unmelt it, I get a 6-row array with lots of blanks!

```
df2.pivot(columns = 'variable', values = 'value')


variable  asset1  asset2
0            1.0     NaN
1            3.0     NaN
2            5.0     NaN
3            NaN     2.0
4            NaN     4.0
5            NaN     6.0
```

Is there any way to preserve the 'coper' part of my indexing while using melt?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You need preserve index values by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and parameter `id_vars`:

```
df2 = pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars='index',value_vars=['asset1','asset2'])
print (df2)
    index variable  value
0  coper1   asset1      1
1  coper2   asset1      3
2  coper3   asset1      5
3  coper1   asset2      2
4  coper2   asset2      4
5  coper3   asset2      6
```

Then pivot working nice:

```
print(df2.pivot(index='index',columns = 'variable', values = 'value'))
variable  asset1  asset2
index                   
coper1         1       2
coper2         3       4
coper3         5       6
```

Another possible solution with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df2 = df.stack().reset_index()
df2.columns = list('abc')
print (df2)
        a       b  c
0  coper1  asset1  1
1  coper1  asset2  2
2  coper2  asset1  3
3  coper2  asset2  4
4  coper3  asset1  5
5  coper3  asset2  6

print(df2.pivot(index='a',columns = 'b', values = 'c'))
b       asset1  asset2
a                     
coper1       1       2
coper2       3       4
coper3       5       6
```

Answer (score 23):

set the ignore_index to be False to preserve the index, e.g.

```
df = df.melt(var_name=‘species’, value_name=‘height’, ignore_index = False)
```

Comment: Note: This requires pandas >= 1.1

Answer (score 4):

Looks like "optional argument keep_index to dataframe melt method" got into release 1.1: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17440

Comment: It seems, it is actually called "ignore_index": https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html