# python polars DataFrame trasformation

Tags: python, dataframe, transpose, python-polars

Consider the following code:

```
import polars as pl
R=pl.DataFrame({"R":["r1","r2","r3"]})
C=pl.DataFrame({"C":["c1","c2",]})
RC=R.join(C,how="cross")
RC=RC.with_columns(pl.Series(name="VAL",values=range(1,7)))
print(RC)

shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ R   ┆ C   ┆ VAL │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ str ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ r1  ┆ c1  ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ r1  ┆ c2  ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ r2  ┆ c1  ┆ 3   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ r2  ┆ c2  ┆ 4   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ r3  ┆ c1  ┆ 5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ r3  ┆ c2  ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘

RC2=pl.DataFrame({"R":["r1","r2","r3"],"c1":[1,3,5],"c2":[2,4,6]})
print(RC2)

shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ R   ┆ c1  ┆ c2  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ r1  ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ r2  ┆ 3   ┆ 4   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ r3  ┆ 5   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

what is the best way to transform RC in RC2 ? I was thinking about a a series of groupby operations but there should be a better solution... and from RC2 back to RC?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [pandas pivot method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```py
RC2 = RC.pivot(values='VAL', index='R', columns='C')
```

---

Results:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ R   ┆ c1  ┆ c2  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ r1  ┆ 1   ┆ 2   │
│ r2  ┆ 3   ┆ 4   │
│ r3  ┆ 5   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Now turning `RC2` back to `RC` exactly is not really an option as we've lost the order, but I would suggest reading about the [pandas melt method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50529022/pandas-melt-unmelt-preserve-index)

Comment: thanks to your answer I found the same function in polars